# populating form with data from session; django

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering how to fill my form with data that i have stored in my session.
my model:

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_by = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    order_status = ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    address_street = CharField(max_length=256)
    address_postal_code = CharField(max_length=18)
    address_city = CharField(max_length=128)
    shipping = ForeignKey(ShippingMethod, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    payment = DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=False)
    payment_method = ForeignKey(PaymentMethod, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

I have a view that stores my choices in 'cart'

```
class AddProductToCartView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        cart = request.session.get("cart")
        if cart:
            for item in cart:
                if item["id"] == pk:
                    item["quantity"] += 1
                    break
            else:
                cart.append({"id": pk, "quantity": 1})
            request.session["cart"] = cart
        else:
            request.session["cart"] = [{"id": pk, "quantity": 1}]
        return redirect("store:cart_view")

class CartView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        in_cart = []
        overall_price = 0
        overall_tax = 0
        if "cart" in request.session:
            overall_price = 0
            for item in request.session["cart"]:
                product = Product.objects.select_related("category").get(id=item["id"])
                total_price = product.price * item["quantity"]
                tax = (total_price * product.tax)
                in_cart.append({
                    "product": product,
                    "quantity": item["quantity"],
                    "total_price": total_price,
                    "tax": tax
                })
                overall_price += total_price
                overall_tax += tax
        return render(
            request,
            template_name="cart/cart_view.html",
            context={
                "products": in_cart if len(in_cart) > 0 else None,
                "overall_price": overall_price,
                "overall_tax": overall_tax
            }
        )
```

and I want to populate my form with data (some of it not everything is in my 'cart' so still i hate to take info from the user from a form.

I get that i want to create a form with certain data:

```
class AddAditionalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['certain fields']
```

and in the views.py

```
class CheckOutView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddAditionalDataForm
    template_name = 'check_form/check_out_form.html'
```

I don't what a finish solution more like a hint in witch direction to go with this ?

Comment: **Note:** `__str__()` method must return data of `str` not `int` currently self.id is of int type, so I'd recommend you to use f-strings so it should be `return f"{self.id}"` the comment is not the answer to the main problem, but it's a kind of improvement.

Answer (score 0):

To populate a form from multiple data sources, you can simply merge those data sources, and use the new data.

```
# request.POST is immutable by default. 
# .copy() will make a new, mutable copy. 
data = request.POST.copy()
data['cart'] = request.sessions.get('cart')

form = AddAdditionalDataForm(data)
```

Two more things I want to mention.

1. It is not a good practice using user submitted data without validating. What if `pk` does not match any existing `Product`?
2. Your `Order` model has no field related to `Product`. I am not sure if this is intended, but having an additional model describing order list has several benefits.

2.1 Order detail is now traceable.

2.2 Discount can be applied to individual order.

2.3 Product statistics now include sales data.

```
# Example order item definition
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

In such case, form validation becomes a little more complicate

```
ItemFormSet = modelformset_factory(OrderItem, fields=['product', 'quantity', 'price'])

class CheckOutView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddAdditionalDataForm
    template_name = 'check_form/check_out_form.html'
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        # NOTE formset identifies different item data by their prefix,
        # and requires additional management data. i.e.
        # cart_data = {
        #     'item-0-pk': 17, 'item-0-quantity': 1,
        #     'item-1-pk': 28, 'item-1-quantity': 3,
        #     'item-INITIAL_FORMS': 0,
        #     'item-TOTAL_FORMS': 2}
        cart_data = get_cart_data(request.session.get('cart'))
        items_formset = ItemFormSet(cart_data)
        # Save order only when both forms are valid.
        if order_form.is_valid() and items_formset.is_valid()
            order = order_form.save()
            items = items_formset.save(commit=False)
            for item in items:
                item.order = order
            OrderItem.objects.bulk_create(items)
            return redirect(...)
        else:
            ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Include empty formset in get request. 
        # NOTE not to override form and formset containing error data in post request. 
        ...
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly, I have another model: ```class UnitOrder(models.Model):
    order_id = ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    product_id = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = IntegerField(null=False)
```